# What does cross to bear really means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In *The Lego Batman Movie*, computer say this words to Batman:

> Computer: You also have beautiful abs, sir.
>
> Batman: That's my **cross to bear**.

Google says it is English Idiom, but meaning of it confusing in this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately it is a reference to the ancient practice of execution by crucifixion, where the person was attached to a large wooden cross and left to die, and specifically to the carrying of the cross by Jesus of Nazareth, who is central to Christianity.

A "cross to bear" has come to mean a hardship that one must endure.

When the "hardship" is not really a hardship at all, as here, the exaggeration is meant to be a joke of some kind. If the speaker is serious and does not believe he is exaggerating, then he is being portrayed as outrageously solipsistic, totally lacking in perspective.